# Angular Material - How can I close/hide my md-select when I close my menu?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using `md-menu-item` elements in my `md-menu`. The menu is activated by a button - all is working fine and all uses default angular js.

Within each `md-menu-item` I have `md-select` inputs. It looks like this:

```
...

<md-menu-item>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>My Label</label>
        <md-select name="myName" aria-label="My Label" ng-model="mv.myModel" ng-change="vm.onChangeEvent(foo)">
            <md-option ng-value="value" ng-repeat="foo in vm.bar | orderBy: 'name'">
                {{foo.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</md-menu-item>

...
```

If I open the menu via clicking the button - If I choose nothing and I click off of the `<md-select>` (anywhere on screen) the `md-menu` goes away like it should & all is well.

If I click into one of the `<md-select>` elements, then click somewhere in the screen, the `<md-menu>` closes, but I can still see the `<md-select>` element.

Is there a way to "nest" select elements within a menu item so that when I close the menu item, all child elements also close?

[Here is a codepen example](http://codepen.io/damonjentree/pen/yaKWyQ) of what I am seeing.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I think from a User Interface perspective, it's working as expected. If the menu is dropdowned, it makes sense that it stays on the screen prompting the user to make a selection before leaving. Other that that, my advice is to look into the AM directives and see what code makes the menu close once an option is selected, and trigger it the same way.

Comment: Would be neat if we could add a custom class to the backdrop as per this line: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/select/select.js#L1249

Answer (score 2):

To hide md-select when you click outside the box . I am using `'$mdSelect.hide()'` to close md-select dropdown menu. I just put following 3 lines in my main controller.

```
    $(document).bind('click', function (event) {
        $mdSelect.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with `menu` and `select` backdrops which are used to close corresponding elements, when clicked out. So it's angular material thing. You can change `z-index` of these backdrops. Defaults are specified in `variables.scss` file (as you can see menu's backdrop is above select's, so you close it first):

```
$z-index-menu: 100 !default;
$z-index-calendar-pane: 100 !default;
$z-index-select: 90 !default;
```

That's the only quick fix I see (you can change z-index for these backdrops just in your css).