# Md-select multiple doesn't close in md-menu

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to use a multiple md-select in a md-menu. I am trying to close the multiple select after the selection was made, but it doesn't work. I can close the multiple select only if I click outside the menu twice. On the first click the menu is closing and on the second click the multiple select is getting closed. I tried to use z-index but doesn't work.

```
<md-menu >
    <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.openMenu($mdMenu, $event)"></md-button>
    <md-menu-content width="6">
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Steps</label>
                <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedSteps" multiple >
                    <md-option ng-value=1>Step1</md-option>
                    <md-option ng-value=2>Step2</md-option>
                    <md-option ng-value=3>Step3</md-option>
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>
        </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922548/angular-material-how-can-i-close-hide-my-md-select-when-i-close-my-menu

Comment: It is not a duplicate. In my case I am using multi select. The multi select has a different behavior.

Comment: Maybe provide the script you have for attempting to close the select